# Disabling forced windows restart

Tags: windows-7

So last night I got a message effectively telling me that my computer was going to restart, whether or not I liked it:

[image: Forced Restart]

The computer, of course, restarted at 3:00AM like it said it would. However, I would rather not have this happen. I have already enabled the option `No auto-restart with logged on users scheduled automatic updates installation` within gpedit, so why is this popping up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Click on Start menu, type `regedit`, and press
   <kbd>Enter</kbd> keys
2. In regedit navigate to
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU`
3. If you don't have the **WindowsUpdate** key, just create it.
   Right-click on the **Windows** key in the left pane and select **New**
   -> **Key**. Name the key **WindowsUpdate**
4. Right-click on the newly created **WindowsUpdate** key and create a
   new one with the name **AU**
5. Select the **AU** key and, in the right pane create the new key via
   right-click on the empty space and select **New** > **DWORD (32-bit)
   Value**.
6. Set the name `NoAutoRebootWithLoggedOnUsers` for the new DWORD
7. Double-click on the `NoAutoRebootWithLoggedOnUsers` DWORD and set
   the value to **1**.
8. Reboot computer

This registry tweak will prevent Windows to force your computer to reboot after installing updates

Comment: Wouldn't this be the same as the gpedit option though?

Comment: gpedit is available for non-Home users. But before I switched to W8, my W7 ultimate restarted even after I changed gpedit. This registry tweak is actually the one that did the job. I haven't investigated too much why gpedit variant failed for me, since i got what I need via this tweak

Comment: Interesting, though would you have any insight as to why this might have started recently?

Comment: Can't edit on my phone... but regedit automatically starts as admin, so you don't need the ctrl shift enter. Also, it's not del to push

Comment: Vote up for noticing :)